# EmguCV 2.4.2 dll file size are too big

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, face-recognition

I have implented a face detection webapp using EmguCV 2.2.1.
The total dll file size for the webapp to run is just ~12MB.

But when I try to update my program using EmguCV 2.4.2 (I need new FaceRecognizer class in this version), the total dll size is too big.

opencv_gpu242.dll ~ 200MB  (In the 2.2.1 it's just 500KB)

cublas32_42_9.dll ~ 100MB

My webapp is hosted on a server, the storage disk is just about ~300MB so I can't upload my new version. Can anyone tell me how to reduce the size of the dll or use something else?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How can in every build I have to up 500Mb+ to server? That's insane. Even if I remove some files that I don't use (I don't use GPU stuff for eg.) EmguCV crashes. That's insane or I'm doing something wrong too.

Comment: Got exactly the same issue. Did you find a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldnt post as comment and and thats why posting this as an answer. Try with "Release mode". Release modes will reduce the executable size. If it is already compiled in released mode. skip this.

Edit: To reduce the size of EmguCV dll : You can avoid using dll's if there is static libraries for the same. You can do static linking for this.

Comment: The executable file size is small. But what I'm trying to do is reduce the size of the EmguCV dll.

Comment: I dont know about EmguCV. But normally static linking could help? Can you rebuild the EmguCV and make static libraries?